# icu4c--> ushape.c missing character in shaping?

Tags: icu

in our langauge we use arabic characters in writing with some differences,
icu's ushape.c ( arabic shaper) only works with main arabic characters and dosn't shape my language specific characters ( i.e 0x6D5 etc) i'v changed ushape.c to work with my language and it worked well except for on character, that is 0x649, in arabic they have only 2 shapes, in my langauge we have 4 shapes for it.

i'v changed  line 183

```
1                + 256 * 0x7F,/*0x0649*/
```

to

```
1+2+8             + 256 * 0x98 /*0x649*/
```

and changed line 121

```
static const UChar yehHamzaToYeh[] =
{
/* isolated*/ 0xFEEF,
/* final   */ 0xFEF0
};
```

to

```
static const UChar yehHamzaToYeh[] =
    {
        /* isolated */0xFEEF, 
                       0xFBE8, // my language specific
                      0xFBE9,// my language specific
        /* final */   0xFEF0 
   };
```

from [ushape.c](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/trunk/source/common/ushape.c)

now it can produce 3 shapes with no problem ( the beginning,isolated and final), but middle shape is displayed as a square ( missing character ) .

i tried replacing "* 0x98" with other numbers, but this best i can get.

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Uighur? I discussed with a couple of people about Uighur rendering, not this particular issue but in general.

When you said you get a square, what Unicode character do you get?

What you really should do is to file a bug with ICU and discuss it there. This is a feature request, not a usage question.

My rusty recollection is that for Uighur it makes different use of shaping, and you will want to basically have a different mode on the shaper.

Comment: yes it is Uighur.
i don't know which character is the suqare, it only appears within webkit browser.
btw, jave version of arabic shaper ( icu4j) dosn't have this problem, rather it has a problem of giving middle form of 0x649 while it should give isolated form
thanks for your resposnse, i'll try with icu's mailing list

Comment: Welcome: You should call the function directly and test its input/output.  Otherwise we don't know if some other layer is manipulating it. If you write the ML and or file a bug, you should note what input/output you are expecting and getting. If you can write a test in Java and C that shows the issue that's even better.

Comment: ok, i'll try a test with only shaping and see what character is that suqare .

Answer (score 0):

ICU indeed seems to have problems for shaping with some languages, e.g. Urdu.

Your specific character 649 however is probably not the characters that you are looking for.

[U+649 is alef maksura](http://codepoints.net/U+649) which looks identical to [Farsi Yeh U+6cc](http://codepoints.net/U+6cc) which is shaped properly by ICU.

They do have different presentation forms: 
Alef maksura only has isolated and final form: [U+feef](http://codepoints.net/U+feef) [U+fef0](http://codepoints.net/U+fef0)
Farsi yeh has all four forms: [U+fbfc](http://codepoints.net/U+fbfc) [U+fbfd](http://codepoints.net/U+fbfd) [U+fbfe](http://codepoints.net/U+fbfe) [U+fbff](http://codepoints.net/U+fbff)